# BCS External list login failed error

Tags: sharepoint-online, bcs

I have created external list from external content type, external content created from Azure SQL Database, but when i open the list it gives me following error.

Cannot connect to the LobSystem (External System). Reason: 'Cannot open database "Database" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'User'.'

Answer (score 0):

This problem might occur because of the `connections authentication mode` is not assigned to `BDC Identity`.

[image]

See the solution at [Login failed for user ‘NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’ in SharePoint Business Connectivity Service](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/10/10/login-failed-for-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon-in-sharepoint-2010-bcs/)

Check also [Access Denied by Business Data Connectivity in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2011/08/19/create-external-list/)

Comment: When i use "BDC Identity" it gives me error "The metadata object that has Name <Name> has a Property with name ‘AuthenticationMode‘ and value ‘RevertToSelf‘. This value indicates that the runtime should revert to the identity of the application pool, but reverting to the application pool is not permitted for patitioned application service".